# Project dictionary whose value is a dictionary into a new dictionary whose value is an aggregate

Tags: c#, linq

I have the input in the following format:

```
var input = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<string, int>>
{
    { 0, new Dictionary<string, int> { { "January", 10 }, { "February", 2 } } },
    { 1, new Dictionary<string, int> { { "January", 15 }, { "February", 4 } } },
    { 2, new Dictionary<string, int> { { "January", 5 }, { "February", 16 } } }
};
```

I would like to convert this to a variable of type `Dictionary<string, int>` where each value is the sum of the values in the inner dictionary. For the example given, the output should be:

```
var output = new Dictionary<string, int> { { "January", 30 }, { "February", 22 } };
```

How can I accomplish this? LINQ would be preferable if possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't need the `key` of parent dictionary you can flatten the inner dictionary using [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).ASPx) and then group it based on the `Key` of inner dictionary like:

```
 Dictionary<string, int> dictionary =  
                          input.SelectMany(r => r.Value)
                          .GroupBy(r => r.Key)
                          .ToDictionary(grp => grp.Key, grp => grp.Sum(t => t.Value));
```

Comment: I will never beat the top speed-LINQers on SO

Answer (score 1):

Without group by:

```
 input.SelectMany((x) => x.Value)
    .Aggregate( new Dictionary<string,int>(),
      (old,next) => 
       { old[next.Key] = old.ContainsKey(next.Key) ? old[next.Key] + next.Value : next.Value; 
         return old;
       } );
```